# What is the right way to redirect to a different URL inside the WEB application?

Tags: node.js, redirect, express

I have a very small "lab" app that I am writing for learning proposes.
This consist of a login page, and after a successful login a single page app. Back end in Node.js with Express.js and client side is Angular.js

I am successfully serving the login page with res.sendFile when the page is initially requested, but when I detect a successfull login I send the main APP page, but nothing happens.

Here is the code

when a successful login happens, redirect to the app page

```
var loginRequest = function( req, res, next ) {

var user = req.body.user;
var password = req.body.pass;

if ( user === '' || password === '' ) {

    //Some field is blank - insufficient information
    console.log('User login failure: Insufficient data');
    res.json(400, {});

} else {
    models.account.loginRequest ( user, password, function ( result )    {
    console.log ( result );
    if ( result != null ) {
        console.log('Login Succesful');
        userSession = req.session;
        userSession.user = user;
        res.redirect( 301,  '../app' );

    } else {
        console.log('Login NOT Succesful');
        res.status(401).json({});
    }
    });
}

}
```

In the above code the intention is that when I have a successful login I redirect to the app page with a session already created.

`res.redirect( 301,  '../app' );`

then, then this /app path is requested, the below code server it

```
var serveApp = function( req, res, next ) {

console.log('--- sending app.html --- *hopefully');
var options = {
    root: publicPath,
    dotfiles: 'deny',
    headers: {
    'x-timestamp': Date.now(),
    'x-sent': true
    }
};

res.sendFile( 'app.html', options);

};
```

You notice there are sever console.log() just for trying to understand what is happening. What I see on the node console is:

```
POST /users/loginRequest 301 9.266 ms - 40
--- sending app.html --- *hopefully
GET /app 200 41.145 ms - 140
```

and on the developer tools on Chrome I can see that the file was served, but on the Chrome itself it never moves from the page asking for user and password credentials.

Can you please help me to understand why this is not working or, if I am doing it the wrong way, what is the right way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I case that is useful for someone, in the end what I did was answer with a response 200 from node and handle the redirection on Angular

```
angular.module('loginToApp', [])
.constant ( 'loginURL', '/users/loginRequest')
.controller ( 'loginCtrl', function( $scope, $http, $window, loginURL ) {

    $scope.data = [
    { inEmail: '', inPass: '', loginError: false }
    ];

    $scope.loginRequest = function( user, pass ) {

    console.log('--- LoginRequest ---');
    console.log('User: ' + user);
    console.log('Pass: ' + pass);
    console.log('LoginRequest: ' + loginURL );

    $http.post ( loginURL,
             {
             user: user,
             pass: pass
             },
             { withCredentials: true })

        .success ( function( data, status, headers, config ) {
        console.log('--- SUCCESS ---');
        console.log('Data');
        console.log(data);
        console.log('Status');
        console.log(status);
        console.log('Headers');
        console.log(headers);
        console.log('Config');
        console.log(config);

        var appWindow = 'http://' + $window.location.host + data.appPath;
        console.log('--- APP window ---');
        console.log(appWindow);
        console.log('--- APP window ends ---');
        $window.location.href = appWindow;

        })
        .error ( function( data, status, headers, config ) {
        console.log('--- ERROR ---');
        console.log('Data');
        console.log(data);
        console.log('Status');
        console.log(status);
        console.log('Headers');
        console.log(headers);
        console.log('Config');
        console.log(config);

        if ( status != 301 ) {
            loginError ( true );
        }
    });
    };

    var loginError = function( bool ) {
    $scope.data.loginError = bool;
    }

});
```

Of course, the console.log are only a beginner way (such I am myself) of understand what is happening, but not necessary.